# Is the image of characteristic subgroup is normal?

Tags: group-theory

In general, the image of normal subgroups is not normal.

My question is :

Is the image of characteristic subgroup is normal?

Comment: I guess you want the homomorphism to be surjective, otherwise the answer is an uninteresting "No", $\varphi(G)$ has no reason to be normal in $H$, but $G$ is trivially a characteristic subgroup of itself.

Comment: Just for the record: If the homomorphism is surjective, then the image of normal subgroups is normal, contradicting the first statement (if he really has surjective maps in mind...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a counterexample to both your questions: let $\phi: S_3 \rightarrow S_4$ the canonical embedding. $A_3$ is characteristic in $S_3$ and hence normal in $S_3$. But clearly the image $\phi[A_3]$ is not normal and hence not characteristic in $S_4$.